# Linux Network timers are off for a SFTP connection

Tags: linux, networking, sftp

In my application I'm performing SFTP operation.
At one point due to a so far unidentified reason SFTP hangs endlessly.

When I ran

```
netstat -nop
tcp 0 52 192.168.10.160:ssh 192.168.10.66:56832 ESTABLISHED off
```

However,
I have configured keep alive timer specific information in sysctl.conf.

***Scenario:***
Initially when connection was established and i have seen

```
tcp 0 0 192.168.10.160:49196 192.168.10.57:8000 ESTABLISHED keepalive (220.46/0/0)
```

When SFTP transfer is initiated

```
tcp 0 52 192.168.10.160:ssh 192.168.10.66:56832 ESTABLISHED on (0.22/0/0)
```

Finally, When SFTP stalls

```
tcp 0 52 192.168.10.160:ssh 192.168.10.66:56832 ESTABLISHED off
```

How to find why both Keep Alive timer and Re-transmission timer aren't started?